# Radio Buttonset with JqueryUI - change on selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I found this great jqueryui buttonset script here on stackoverflow. It was meant for checkbox and I needed it for radio buttons.

Here: http://jsbin.com/eyonu5

Basically what I want it to do is swap the icon based on the current selection. Right now it only swaps in or out the icon based on the click on only radio button.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't isn't the most efficient way to write this... **but it works**. [The edit on your jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/eyonu5/4)

---

```
var noIcon = {primary: null, secondary: null}
var withIcon = {primary: 'ui-icon-custom-tick', secondary: null};

$('input[name="mainautoresize"]:radio').change(function() {
    if( $('input:not(:has(:radio:checked))') ) {
        $('input:not(:has(:radio:checked))').button("option", "icons", noIcon).button('refresh');
    }

    if($('input:radio:checked') ) {
        $(this).button("option", "icons", withIcon).button('refresh');
    }
});

$('#mainautoresize').buttonset();​
```